# I get a bash syntax error message every time I open Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I've been getting this error for the past couple of months and I wonder if it's a major issue, and how do I fix it?

When I open terminal on my Mac I get this bash error:

```
~bash: /Users/admin/.bash_profile: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'
~bash: /Users/admin/.bash_profile:line 1: 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; than eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi'
```

Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Well, that "than" should probably be "then" but I'm not really a scripting expert.  (Are you logging in to the "admin" account or is something else referencing the admin profile?)

Comment: Login as `admin` and start `TextEdit`. Open `.bash_profile` and correct the typo.

Comment: There isn't a .bash_profile file in admin?

Answer (score 1):

Open the Terminal.app and type the following line at your prompt

```
sed -i '' 's/than/then/' .bash_profile
```

You do have a .bash_profile in your home directory.

Comment: @dmsquare please mark this as the accepted answer if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 1):

To add a little information to fd0's terse answer.

First, you do indeed have a file `.bash_profile` in admin's home folder - you just can't see it as all files with a name that starts `.` are invisible. In the Terminal type `ls -A` and you will see them all.

Second, your problem is that something or someone has added a line to the file containing a syntax error. The `than` should be `then` as it is part of an if-then statement. Open the file in your favourite text editor (if you don't have one then newcomers seem to find `nano` usable so `nano .bash_profile` in Terminal should do it) and change the line.